# How can I split text files by counting characters and find space (without dividing words ) between 30 and 40 characters

Tags: linux

This command splits text file by 30 characters. It also divide words but I need help for split text without divide the word find space between 30 and 40 after that split text file.

```
sed -e 's/.\{30\}/&\n/g' filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a proper lib, like in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). The name for this is *text wraping* :

```
perl -MText::Wrap -lne '
    $Text::Wrap::columns = 30;
    print wrap("", "", $_)
' file
```